Is there a way to reduce the initial startup time for FFmpeg when muxing subtitles?
When I run the FFmpeg command:
./ffmpeg.exe -i video.mkv -map 0:V -map 0:a:0 -c:a copy -c:v copy -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+faststart -strict unofficial file.mp4

It starts almost immediately, which is perfect. However, if I add the subtitles stream like this:
./ffmpeg.exe -i video.mkv -c:s mov_text -map 0:V -map 0:a:0 -map 0:s:0 -c:a copy -c:v copy -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+faststart -strict unofficial file.mp4

It takes a long time to preprocess the entire file before it outputs anything.
Is there a way to make FFmpeg process the subtitles as it goes instead of preprocessing?
For context, I am trying to use it for realtime transcoding and for large files, the initial processing time causes timeouts.

Run ./ffmpeg.exe -i video.mkv -map 0:V -c:v copy -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+faststart -strict unofficial video.mp4 -report -benchmark and ./ffmpeg.exe -i video.mkv -c:s mov_text -map 0:s:0 -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+faststart -strict unofficial subs.mp4 -report -benchmark and share link to reports.

Great to meet you Gyan, I have been using your FFmpeg builds for a long time and including them in Universal Media Server. Thank you so much for providing them!
The logs are https://www.universalmediaserver.com/uploads/gyan-video.log and https://www.universalmediaserver.com/uploads/gyan-subs.log
I believe the problem is visible in the subs logs where you can see size=       0KiB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A many times

The total runtime in both commands is the same (132s). What the progress time jumps in the sub command indicates is that the subs are stored in a few chunks across the file rather than evenly interleaved along with the A/V or all in one packet upfront. You can run ffprobe -v 0 -select_streams s:0 -show_entries packet=pos,pts_time -of compact=p=0 -i video.mkv -o sub-pos.txt to confirm this. If so, it may help to input the file again as a 2nd input and map the subs from there.

I see, yes the output looks like many uneven time chunks. I think the second input method starts faster, that's interesting. It's hard to know which hard drive caching though so I will keep testing. Thank you for your help
